# How to track down module conflict

Tags: java, module

In order to use `java.net.http` I've ended up having to have a `module-info.java` file in my application. This has:

```
module web {
    requires java.net.http;
    requires spring.data.rest.core;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.context;
    requires lombok;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires org.apache.commons.collections4;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.data.rest.webmvc;
    requires spring.jdbc;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires spring.webmvc;
}
```

But when I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package org.objectweb.asm.signature in both module asm and module lombok

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(running from IntelliJ if that matters).

Since I'm not directly including the `asm` module, I'm stumped on how to track down the issue here.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you had to add a module-info.java. AFAIK it is not required to modularize your application to use such APIs.

Comment: Got the same question as @MA . Java Modules aren't really useful for normal applications. Or are you writing some kind of library / framework?

Comment: I had been unable to access java.net.http classes without using the modules.